# How can I use one column in the proc document class?

Tags: titles, two-column, templates

I'm making a 5 pages report about this year's activities. Using the proceedings document class I managed to get very close to the format I've been required to use, but I just can't make it to work with only one column! How can I make a one column document using the proc document class? if I use:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,onecolumn]{proc}
```

I get this error:

```
! Class proc Error: Option `onecolumn' not supported.
```

the beggining of the document is:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{proc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{my header}  
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

%opening
\title{ bla bla bla }

\author{ me }

\begin{document}
\onecolumn

\maketitle

document bla bla bla
```

Comment: Some motivation behind this behaviour: The `proc` documentclass calls `\PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}`, forcing it to be typeset in `twocolumn` mode. A better question, based on @lockstep's answer is, why don't you just use a regular (say) `article` document class and specify your margins using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)?

Comment: @Werner: mainly because the first page is not like I need at all. First because the big space above the title, and second it does not display the header on the first page. If I could overcome that, I would use the article class.

Comment: I retagged to [tag:two-column] because this question is in effect about *removing* the effects of the `twocolumn` class option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a brief mockup of a possible switch to the `article` document class. A comparison to what your MWE compiled under the `proc` document class is also provided.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[
  letterpaper,%
  textheight={47\baselineskip+\topskip},%
  textwidth={\paperwidth-126pt},%
  footskip=75pt,%
  marginparwidth=0pt,%
  top={\topskip+0.75in}]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot{}% Clear header & footer
\fancyhead[C]{my header}% Set centered header
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Set centered footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}% Add header rule

% Titling
\title{ bla bla bla }% Your title
\author{ me }% Your author
\date{ \today }% Your date
\makeatletter
% Definition of proc.cls' \maketitle:
\def\@maketitle{% 
  \vbox to 2.25in{%
    \hsize\textwidth
    \linewidth\hsize
    \vfil
    \centering
    {\LARGE \@title \par}
    \vskip 2em
    {\large \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author \end{tabular}\par}
    \vfil}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle % Produce title
\thispagestyle{fancy}% Override titling page style with fancy

\lipsum[1-10]% Your document text
\end{document}
```

[image]

The layout is not 100% perfect in comparison with your original MWE, but I'm not sure how close you want to have them match. Some of the length choices were based on scanning [`proc.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/proc.cls). You mentioned the spacing around the title. I copied the `\@maketitle` macro from `proc` and used it as-is in my MWE to produce the exact same spacing around the title.  The only difference seems to be in the margins, which can be adjusted as needed via `geometry`'s easy-to-use interface.

Additional packages included are: [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) for infix length arithmetic, [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) for dummy text creates (*Lorem Ipsum* style), [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for page layout (margins, stock, text area, ...) formatting.

Comment: Your answer deserves to be the accepted one. But now I'm *again* behind egreg rep-wise for today ... ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: Well, aren't we all...

Answer (score 6):

Issue `\onecolumn` immediately after `\begin{document}`.

Note: The small margins of the `proc` class are *not at all* suited for a one-column document with a font size of 10pt. You might want to increase the margins and/or the font size.

EDIT: In response to your edited question: `\maketitle` does indeed (for whatever reason) switch back to `\twocolumn`. In my updated example, I use the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to selectively alter the definition of `\maketitle`. (Please consider to switch to the `article` class as suggested by Werner.)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{proc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\twocolumn[\@maketitle]}{\@maketitle}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{bla bla bla}
\author{me}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\onecolumn

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't work... I get a first page with the Loren Ipsum thing, and the next page is a two colums page. I'm editing the question to add the preamble of my tex file.